# How to create such a text?

Tags: android, textview

How can i create this "$" ? [image]

I do not even know the name of it is to search in Google

@Bidhan A

[image]

Comment: You mean the dollar sign?

Comment: yes, it occupies the upper half of line

Comment: see android.text.style.SuperscriptSpan

Comment: You use Custom Font??

Comment: Dilavar, yes i use Custom Font

Comment: simple.reduce first text size of $ symbol and increase second text size of price.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is as follows:

```
TextView price= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.superscript);
price.setText(Html.fromHtml("<sup><small>$</small></sup>59.12"));
```

Edit: Okay if you want their tops to align, then the above method wont work for you. You're going to have to do some extra work. Do the following

1. First, create a new Java file and call it SpanAdjuster.java . Then paste the following code

   ```
    import android.text.TextPaint;
    import android.text.style.MetricAffectingSpan;

    public class SpanAdjuster extends MetricAffectingSpan {
    double ratio = 0.5;

    public SpanAdjuster() {
    }

    public SpanAdjuster(double ratio) {
     this.ratio = ratio;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint paint) {
      paint.baselineShift += (int) (paint.ascent() * ratio);
    }

    @Override
      public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
    paint.baselineShift += (int) (paint.ascent() * ratio);
   }
   }
   ```
2. Now, inside your MainActivity

   ```
   TextView price= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
   SpannableStringBuilder cs = new SpannableStringBuilder("$59.12");
   //Make the dollar sign smaller that the rest of the text
   cs.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.7f), 0, 1, SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   // Align it to the top
   cs.setSpan(new SpanAdjuster(1.6/5.0), 0, 1, SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

   price.setText(cs);
   ```
3. Adjust the values inside RelativeSizeSpan() and SpanAdjuster() according to your text size.

I hope the above works for you.

Comment: cool! but "$" above the text, and should be at the same level.

Comment: This gives you exactly what you want. Did you not try it?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I got, as the second image. I added the question. I need to in the first picture, the upper part of the text was the same height

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:drawableLeft` to `TextView` like this

```
<TextView
       ...
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dollar_sign"
      ...
/>
```

Comment: I do not think it was a good decision. I do not want to cut the picture with this sign, and I hope that there are standard solutions. Sometimes, instead of the icon can be an entire line in this case. it also makes the picture?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with the below example:

```
String styledText = "<small > <font size='10'  color='#1373CC'><b>"
            + "ABC " + "</b></font></small>" 
            + "<font size='30'  color='#1373CC'><b>" + "Testing" + "</b></font>";
    tv_textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));
```